# Windows Active memory dump

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-10, dump, wmic

Windows 10 has a new feature - [active memory dump](https://chentiangemalc.wordpress.com/2014/10/02/windows-10active-memory-dump/).

I would like to get / set currently set dump type in windows 10. To get dump type I use the following command in command prompt:

```
wmic RECOVEROS get DebugInfoType
```

which returns integer value assigned to certain type.

The problem is that both **Active Memory Dump** and **Complete Memory Dump** has value assigned equal to **1** so I can't tell which of the latter is selected. and if I use

```
wmic RECOVEROS set DebugInfoType = 1
```

then **Complete Memory Dump** is set.

Is there any way I can read the currently selected dump type via cmd or registry? Or i need some UI Automation tool to read the value from the window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Active Memory Dump feature is controlled by the **FilterPages** registry value at HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\CrashControl

When **DebugInfoType** is **1** and **FilterPages** is set to **1**, UI will show "Active Memory Dump", otherwise it will show "Complete Memory Dump".